# AWS EC2 windows instance, can't seem to open port 80 or 433 for NodeJs, ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I've checked around and managed to open port 80 and 433 in the "windows firewall with advanced security" and also added that the program: node.exe is the program allowed to use those ports. However when I do netstat -an/aon port 80 and 433 don't seem to be listening.

When I try to start up the application I can find the website in localhost:3000 but when trying to access it through the public dns I seem to fail. I've been pondering if it might be the line of code in ***www.js***:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
```

Who might be the culprit. To add i've also allowed in the security group used by the EC2 instance to allow port 80 and 433.

Below is the output of netstat -aon

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       652
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1532
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5985           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:47001          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       420
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       724
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       800
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       512
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49157          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       520
  TCP    172.31.24.18:3389      176.10.230.225:58167   ESTABLISHED     1532
  TCP    172.31.24.18:49190     169.254.169.254:80     CLOSE_WAIT      1168
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING       652
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:3389              [::]:0                 LISTENING       1532
  TCP    [::]:5985              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:47001             [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:49152             [::]:0                 LISTENING       420
  TCP    [::]:49153             [::]:0                 LISTENING       724
  TCP    [::]:49154             [::]:0                 LISTENING       800
  TCP    [::]:49155             [::]:0                 LISTENING       512
  TCP    [::]:49157             [::]:0                 LISTENING       520
  UDP    0.0.0.0:123            *:*                                    852
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3389           *:*                                    1532
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*                                    948
  UDP    [::]:123               *:*                                    852
  UDP    [::]:3389              *:*                                    1532
```

Comment: what is the value of process.env.PORT ??

Comment: It actually has no value from what I can see

Answer (score 0):

From the output, it's not firewall or security groups since the process is not able to create a socket on 80/443.

What I would do to troubleshoot:

1. Use a separate program to try to bind to those ports. In linux I usually use netcat or 'python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80'
2. Ensure it's running with admin privileges. Remember that anything below 1024 requires admin

Answer (score 0):

Install apache … just follow these commands:

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y httpd24
sudo service httpd start
sudo chkconfig httpd on
```

Then, you will see:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: Explaining these commands could help other users understand what they do to prevent unwanted behaviour :)